# Login to page with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a website and I promise no one can log in to it with selenium 
here you are: https://edu.usc.ac.ir/Forms/AuthenticateUser/main.htm

This page has a different code from what you see, and I would like to crawl it with Selenium.

I write the below code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = "https://edu.usc.ac.ir/Forms/AuthenticateUser/main.htm"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("F80351")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("F80401")
```

When I use this code I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"F80351"}``
```

I can't figure out why it can't find the element that exists in this page.

Comment: no i dont want to someone else do it for me , i try solve this problem again and again but i cant , I'm struggling for learn how to solve. this problem , tanx

Comment: eddited ...
i realy appreciate this help  cuase i am a begginer , i dont think this is a problem , you started this way same me , from zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the document, you'll see it's comprised of several frames stacked upon each other.

```
<body ...>
    ...
    <div id="FacArea" style="top: 48px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 672px; height: 572px;">
        <div style="overflow: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 672px; height: 572px;">
            <iframe src="nav.htm?fid=0;1&amp;tck=&amp;" id="Faci1" name="Faci1" width="672" height="572" style="z-index: 2;">
                #document
                <html>
                    ...
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Your username and password input are located in a document 3 frames deep, which is why you can't find them. You need to iteratively find those frames and switch to them.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

frame_names = ('Faci1', 'Master', 'Form_Body')
for name in frame_names:
    frame = driver.find_element_by_name(name)
    driver.switch_to_frame(frame)

username = driver.find_element_by_id('F80351')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('F80401')
```

Comment: thanks  , very very nice answer , it works beautiful  , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not doing anything with the elements that you've found.

Change:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("F80351")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("F80401")
```

To:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("F80351").send_keys('your username')
driver.find_element_by_id("F80401").send_keys('your password')
driver.find_element_by_id("btnLog").click()
```

Comment: hi man 
tanx for it but i suggest you to test it 
here is the error i gave after write your code :
.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"F80351"}

. 
this site is Spellbound you have never seen something like this :))